# How to read RS232 port through PHP

Tags: php, hardware-interface

I'm trying to make a connection using **PHP socket libraries** but its not working is there any alternate way.

```
<?php
include "php_serial.class.php";

// Let's start the class
$serial = new phpSerial;

// First we must specify the device. This works on both linux and windows (if
// your linux serial device is /dev/ttyS0 for COM1, etc)
$serial->deviceSet("COM1");

// Then we need to open it
$serial->deviceOpen();

// To write into
$serial->sendMessage("Hello !");

// Or to read from
$read = $serial->readPort();

// If you want to change the configuration, the device must be closed
$serial->deviceClose();

// We can change the baud rate
$serial->confBaudRate(2400);

// etc...
?>
```

This one is the included file.

### php_serial.class.php::

```
<?php
define ("SERIAL_DEVICE_NOTSET", 0);
define ("SERIAL_DEVICE_SET", 1);
define ("SERIAL_DEVICE_OPENED", 2);

/**
 * Serial port control class
 *
 * THIS PROGRAM COMES WITH ABSOLUTELY NO WARANTIES !
 * USE IT AT YOUR OWN RISKS !
 *
 * @author Rémy Sanchez <thenux@gmail.com>
 * @thanks Aurélien Derouineau for finding how to open serial ports with windows
 * @thanks Alec Avedisyan for help and testing with reading
 * @copyright under GPL 2 licence
 */
class phpSerial
{
    var $_device = null;
    var $_windevice = null;
    var $_dHandle = null;
    var $_dState = SERIAL_DEVICE_NOTSET;
    var $_buffer = "";
    var $_os = "";

    /**
     * This var says if buffer should be flushed by sendMessage (true) or manualy (false)
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    var $autoflush = true;

    /**
     * Constructor. Perform some checks about the OS and setserial
     *
     * @return phpSerial
     */
    function phpSerial ()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");

        $sysname = php_uname();

        if (substr($sysname, 0, 5) === "Linux")
        {
            $this->_os = "linux";

            if($this->_exec("stty --version") === 0)
            {
                register_shutdown_function(array($this, "deviceClose"));
            }
            else
            {
                trigger_error("No stty availible, unable to run.", E_USER_ERROR);
            }
        }
        elseif(substr($sysname, 0, 7) === "Windows")
        {
            $this->_os = "windows";
            register_shutdown_function(array($this, "deviceClose"));
        }
        else
        {
            trigger_error("Host OS is neither linux nor windows, unable tu run.", E_USER_ERROR);
            exit();
        }
    }

    //
    // OPEN/CLOSE DEVICE SECTION -- {START}
    //

    /**
     * Device set function : used to set the device name/address.
     * -> linux : use the device address, like /dev/ttyS0
     * -> windows : use the COMxx device name, like COM1 (can also be used
     *     with linux)
     *
     * @param string $device the name of the device to be used
     * @return bool
     */
    function deviceSet ($device)
    {
        if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_OPENED)
        {
            if ($this->_os === "linux")
            {
                if (preg_match("@^COM(\d+):?$@i", $device, $matches))
                {
                    $device = "/dev/ttyS" . ($matches[1] - 1);
                }

                if ($this->_exec("stty -F " . $device) === 0)
                {
                    $this->_device = $device;
                    $this->_dState = SERIAL_DEVICE_SET;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            elseif ($this->_os === "windows")
            {
                if (preg_match("@^COM(\d+):?$@i", $device, $matches) and $this->_exec(exec("mode " . $device)) === 0)
                {
                    $this->_windevice = "COM" . $matches[1];
                    $this->_device = "\\.\com" . $matches[1];
                    $this->_dState = SERIAL_DEVICE_SET;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            trigger_error("Specified serial port is not valid", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            trigger_error("You must close your device before to set an other one", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Opens the device for reading and/or writing.
     *
     * @param string $mode Opening mode : same parameter as fopen()
     * @return bool
     */
    function deviceOpen ($mode = "r+b")
    {
        if ($this->_dState === SERIAL_DEVICE_OPENED)
        {
            trigger_error("The device is already opened", E_USER_NOTICE);
            return true;
        }

        if ($this->_dState === SERIAL_DEVICE_NOTSET)
        {
            trigger_error("The device must be set before to be open", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        if (!preg_match("@^[raw]\+?b?$@", $mode))
        {
            trigger_error("Invalid opening mode : ".$mode.". Use fopen() modes.", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        $this->_dHandle = @fopen($this->_device, $mode);

        if ($this->_dHandle !== false)
        {
            stream_set_blocking($this->_dHandle, 0);
            $this->_dState = SERIAL_DEVICE_OPENED;
            return true;
        }

        $this->_dHandle = null;
        trigger_error("Unable to open the device", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the device
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    function deviceClose ()
    {
        if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_OPENED)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (fclose($this->_dHandle))
        {
            $this->_dHandle = null;
            $this->_dState = SERIAL_DEVICE_SET;
            return true;
        }

        trigger_error("Unable to close the device", E_USER_ERROR);
        return false;
    }

    //
    // OPEN/CLOSE DEVICE SECTION -- {STOP}
    //

    //
    // CONFIGURE SECTION -- {START}
    //

    /**
     * Configure the Baud Rate
     * Possible rates : 110, 150, 300, 600, 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 38400,
     * 57600 and 115200.
     *
     * @param int $rate the rate to set the port in
     * @return bool
     */
    function confBaudRate ($rate)
    {
        if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_SET)
        {
            trigger_error("Unable to set the baud rate : the device is either not set or opened", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        $validBauds = array (
            110    => 11,
            150    => 15,
            300    => 30,
            600    => 60,
            1200   => 12,
            2400   => 24,
            4800   => 48,
            9600   => 96,
            19200  => 19,
            38400  => 38400,
            57600  => 57600,
            115200 => 115200
        );

        if (isset($validBauds[$rate]))
        {
            if ($this->_os === "linux")
            {
                $ret = $this->_exec("stty -F " . $this->_device . " " . (int) $rate, $out);
            }
            elseif ($this->_os === "windows")
            {
                $ret = $this->_exec("mode " . $this->_windevice . " BAUD=" . $validBauds[$rate], $out);
            }
            else return false;

            if ($ret !== 0)
            {
                trigger_error ("Unable to set baud rate: " . $out[1], E_USER_WARNING);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Configure parity.
     * Modes : odd, even, none
     *
     * @param string $parity one of the modes
     * @return bool
     */
    function confParity ($parity)
    {
        if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_SET)
        {
            trigger_error("Unable to set parity : the device is either not set or opened", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        $args = array(
            "none" => "-parenb",
            "odd"  => "parenb parodd",
            "even" => "parenb -parodd",
        );

        if (!isset($args[$parity]))
        {
            trigger_error("Parity mode not supported", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->_os === "linux")
        {
            $ret = $this->_exec("stty -F " . $this->_device . " " . $args[$parity], $out);
        }
        else
        {
            $ret = $this->_exec("mode " . $this->_windevice . " PARITY=" . $parity{0}, $out);
        }

        if ($ret === 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        trigger_error("Unable to set parity : " . $out[1], E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the length of a character.
     *
     * @param int $int length of a character (5 <= length <= 8)
     * @return bool
     */
    function confCharacterLength ($int)
    {
        if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_SET)
        {
            trigger_error("Unable to set length of a character : the device is either not set or opened", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        $int = (int) $int;
        if ($int < 5) $int = 5;
        elseif ($int > 8) $int = 8;

        if ($this->_os === "linux")
        {
            $ret = $this->_exec("stty -F " . $this->_device . " cs" . $int, $out);
        }
        else
        {
            $ret = $this->_exec("mode " . $this->_windevice . " DATA=" . $int, $out);
        }

        if ($ret === 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        trigger_error("Unable to set character length : " .$out[1], E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the length of stop bits.
     *
     * @param float $length the length of a stop bit. It must be either 1,
     * 1.5 or 2. 1.5 is not supported under linux and on some computers.
     * @return bool
     */
    function confStopBits ($length)
    {
        if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_SET)
        {
            trigger_error("Unable to set the length of a stop bit : the device is either not set or opened", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        if ($length != 1 and $length != 2 and $length != 1.5 and !($length == 1.5 and $this->_os === "linux"))
        {
            trigger_error("Specified stop bit length is invalid", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->_os === "linux")
        {
            $ret = $this->_exec("stty -F " . $this->_device . " " . (($length == 1) ? "-" : "") . "cstopb", $out);
        }
        else
        {
            $ret = $this->_exec("mode " . $this->_windevice . " STOP=" . $length, $out);
        }

        if ($ret === 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        trigger_error("Unable to set stop bit length : " . $out[1], E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Configures the flow control
     *
     * @param string $mode Set the flow control mode. Availible modes :
     *  -> "none" : no flow control
     *  -> "rts/cts" : use RTS/CTS handshaking
     *  -> "xon/xoff" : use XON/XOFF protocol
     * @return bool
     */
    function confFlowControl ($mode)
    {
        if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_SET)
        {
            trigger_error("Unable to set flow control mode : the device is either not set or opened", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        $linuxModes = array(
            "none"     => "clocal -crtscts -ixon -ixoff",
            "rts/cts"  => "-clocal crtscts -ixon -ixoff",
            "xon/xoff" => "-clocal -crtscts ixon ixoff"
        );
        $windowsModes = array(
            "none"     => "xon=off octs=off rts=on",
            "rts/cts"  => "xon=off octs=on rts=hs",
            "xon/xoff" => "xon=on octs=off rts=on",
        );

        if ($mode !== "none" and $mode !== "rts/cts" and $mode !== "xon/xoff") {
            trigger_error("Invalid flow control mode specified", E_USER_ERROR);
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->_os === "linux")
            $ret = $this->_exec("stty -F " . $this->_device . " " . $linuxModes[$mode], $out);
        else
            $ret = $this->_exec("mode " . $this->_windevice . " " . $windowsModes[$mode], $out);

        if ($ret === 0) return true;
        else {
            trigger_error("Unable to set flow control : " . $out[1], E_USER_ERROR);
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets a setserial parameter (cf man setserial)
     * NO MORE USEFUL !
     *  -> No longer supported
     *  -> Only use it if you need it
     *
     * @param string $param parameter name
     * @param string $arg parameter value
     * @return bool
     */
    function setSetserialFlag ($param, $arg = "")
    {
        if (!$this->_ckOpened()) return false;

        $return = exec ("setserial " . $this->_device . " " . $param . " " . $arg . " 2>&1");

        if ($return{0} === "I")
        {
            trigger_error("setserial: Invalid flag", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        elseif ($return{0} === "/")
        {
            trigger_error("setserial: Error with device file", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //
    // CONFIGURE SECTION -- {STOP}
    //

    //
    // I/O SECTION -- {START}
    //

    /**
     * Sends a string to the device
     *
     * @param string $str string to be sent to the device
     * @param float $waitForReply time to wait for the reply (in seconds)
     */
    function sendMessage ($str, $waitForReply = 0.1)
    {
        $this->_buffer .= $str;

        if ($this->autoflush === true) $this->flush();

        usleep((int) ($waitForReply * 1000000));
    }

    /**
     * Reads the port until no new datas are availible, then return the content.
     *
     * @pararm int $count number of characters to be read (will stop before
     *  if less characters are in the buffer)
     * @return string
     */
    function readPort ($count = 0)
    {
        if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_OPENED)
        {
            trigger_error("Device must be opened to read it", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->_os === "linux")
        {
            $content = ""; $i = 0;

            if ($count !== 0)
            {
                do {
                    if ($i > $count) $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, ($count - $i));
                    else $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, 128);
                } while (($i += 128) === strlen($content));
            }
            else
            {
                do {
                    $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, 128);
                } while (($i += 128) === strlen($content));
            }

            return $content;
        }
        elseif ($this->_os === "windows")
        {
            /* Do nohting : not implented yet */
        }

        trigger_error("Reading serial port is not implemented for Windows", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Flushes the output buffer
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    function flush ()
    {
        if (!$this->_ckOpened()) return false;

        if (fwrite($this->_dHandle, $this->_buffer) !== false)
        {
            $this->_buffer = "";
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_buffer = "";
            trigger_error("Error while sending message", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
    }

    //
    // I/O SECTION -- {STOP}
    //

    //
    // INTERNAL TOOLKIT -- {START}
    //

    function _ckOpened()
    {
        if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_OPENED)
        {
            trigger_error("Device must be opened", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    function _ckClosed()
    {
        if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_CLOSED)
        {
            trigger_error("Device must be closed", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    function _exec($cmd, &$out = null)
    {
        $desc = array(
            1 => array("pipe", "w"),
            2 => array("pipe", "w")
        );

        $proc = proc_open($cmd, $desc, $pipes);

        $ret = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        $err = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

        fclose($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[2]);

        $retVal = proc_close($proc);

        if (func_num_args() == 2) $out = array($ret, $err);
        return $retVal;
    }

    //
    // INTERNAL TOOLKIT -- {STOP}
    //
}
?>
```

I am using this way but its not working fine.

Comment: What do you mean by its not working and its not working fine? Does it work partly or totally doesnt work? Does it throw any error? Is the device connected (could you see it somehow?) I don't think there are many guys who are connecting php to rs232, but who knows :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this on Windows as your choice of 'COM1' leads me to believe, then there is a known issue when with the port never timing out. I have successfully over come this using a batch file to start my php script, but calling comconfig.exe first to fix the issue:

```
REM Fix bug with Windows serial port timeout not working
comconfig.exe COM1
php.exe myscript.php
```

I also run the MODE command when my script starts using the following line, but am I not sure this is required (belts and braces though!):

```
exec('MODE COM1 to=on');
```

I had a lot of trouble finding the comconfig.exe program, so I've uploaded it complete with the required vcredist.exe for you:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2770237/comconfig.zip

Comment: Thanks for your response and where can we excute this script               REM Fix bug with Windows serial port timeout not working
comconfig.exe COM1
php.exe myscript.php

Comment: Hi @KGolding, the comconfig.exe is no longer available, could you please give some hints where shall I find it ?

Comment: Hello, here's a new link for the comconfig.exe and vcdist.exe https://nc.lxsig.uk/index.php/s/aCNt2xR4eYKYCra